# Python's OS module to write to file giving "TypeError"

Tags: python, typeerror

Here is my script:

```
import random
import os

i = 0
file = os.open("numbers.txt", "w")
while i < 5000:
    ranNumb = str(random.randint(1,500))
    file.write(ranNumb,",")
```

The end goal is simply a text file with 5000 randomly generated numbers in it that I would like to use in subsequent projects. When I run this little script I get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LewTo002/Desktop/New folder (2)/numGen.py", line 5, in <module>
    file = os.open("numbers.txt", "w")
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

I've reviewed the following sites to solve the problem myself : 
http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

And according to those, I am doing the correctly. The error is thrown specifically due to the "w" in "file = os.open('numbers.txt', 'w')" according to my IDE ( using JetBrain's PyCharm ). I feel like I am overlooking something trivial especially with how simple this script is... Any assistance would be thoroughly appreciated! :)

Comment: Try removing the `os.` part of `os.open` - `open` is a built-in function!

Comment: Uhhg! THAT WAS IT! Thank you :)

Comment: ... and if you want to use low-level IO, you also need `os.write()`. `os.open()` returns a simple `int`, the file descriptor number, it doesn't itself have methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use [os.open](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open) you have to use [os flags](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#open-constants) to identify mode in which you are going to open file:

```
file = os.open("numbers.txt", os.O_WRONLY)
```

The way you are trying to open file is correct for [built in open method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open)

**Good Luck !**

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) you linked:

> If you just want to read or write a file see [open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

As I said in the comment, change this:

```
os.open(...)
```

To this:

```
open(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Citing after Python docs available [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.open)

> This function is intended for low-level I/O. For normal usage, use the built-in function open(), which returns a “file object” with read() and write() methods (and many more). To wrap a file descriptor in a “file object”, use fdopen().

You should use the built-in `open` function as others has said already.